# How to check if the Worksheet already exist in Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I want to check if the sheet exists before creating it.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\"Example".xlsx");


Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets.Add();
int count = wb.Sheets.Count;

sh.Name = "Example";
sh.Cells[1, "A"].Value2 = "Example";
sh.Cells[1, "B"].Value2 = "Example"
wb.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a loop like this:

```
// Keeping track
bool found = false;
// Loop through all worksheets in the workbook
foreach(Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Sheets)
{
    // Check the name of the current sheet
    if (sheet.Name == "Example")
    {
        found = true;
        break; // Exit the loop now
    }
}

if (found)
{
    // Reference it by name
    Worksheet mySheet = wb.Sheets["Example"];
}
else
{
    // Create it
}
```

I'm not into Office Interop very much, but come to think of it, you could also try the following, much shorter way:

```
Worksheet mySheet;
mySheet = wb.Sheets["NameImLookingFor"];

if (mySheet == null)
    // Create a new sheet
```

But I'm not sure if that would simply return `null` without throwing an exception; you would have to try the second method for yourself.

Comment: HI , Thank u If possible can you tell me how to select the existing sheet so the sheet can worked on with

Comment: Thank u it solved my issue :) , the second method throws an exception

Answer (score 16):

This extension method returns the worksheet if it exists, null otherwise:

```
public static class WorkbookExtensions
{
    public static Excel.Worksheet GetWorksheetByName(this Excel.Workbook workbook, string name)
    {
        return workbook.Worksheets.OfType<Excel.Worksheet>().FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.Name == name);
    }
}
```

The linq method .Any() can be used instead of FirstOrDefault to check whether the worksheet exists as well...

Comment: just I used ws.Name.Equals(...) method in lamda expression to allow comparison with ignore case.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do this:

```
try {

    Excel.Worksheet wks = wkb.Worksheets["Example"];

 } catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) {

    // Create the worksheet
 }

 wks.Select();
```

The other way avoids throwing and catching exceptions, and certainly it's a legitimate answer, but I found this and wanted to put this up as an alternative.

Comment: Very old answer, but for anyone coming across this: catching errors is a very expensive process, and should be avoided when possible.